# cascade type save update in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate with JPA annotations for relationship mapping.
I have three entities in my code `User` `Group` & `User_Group`

`User` & `Group` are in a `ManyToMany` relationship.

`User_Group` is a kinda [bridge table but with some additional fields](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-in-join-table-example). So here is the modified mapping code.

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<UserGroup> userGroups
}
```

Group

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS")
public class Group {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
private Set<UserGroup> userGroups
}
```

UserGroup

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS_GROUPS")
public class UserGroup {

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")  
private User user;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID")
private Group group;
}
```

When I set the user & group object to the usergroup & save it.

```
User user = new User("tommy", "ymmot", "tommy@gmail.com");
Group group = new Group("Coders");

UserGroup userGroup = new UserGroup();
userGroup.setGroup(group);
userGroup.setUser(user);
userGroup.setActivated(true);
userGroup.setRegisteredDate(new Date());

session.save(userGroup);
```

Things work fine. With `CascadeType.ALL` the group object & user object are updated too. But when I delete the userGroup object. The child object are deleted too.

Deletion of child objects is a strict no no.

There is no `CascadeType.SAVE-UPDATE` in JPA, which just does save or update but no delete. How do I achieve this.

If I remove the `CascadeType.ALL` from the mapping the child objects don't get updated & I need them to be updated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SAVE_UPDATE is for save(), update(), and saveOrUpdate(), which are 3 Hibernate-proprietary methods. JPA only has `persist()` and `merge()`. So, if you want to use cascading on Hibernate-proprietary methods, you'll need to use Hibernate-proprietary annotations. In this case, [Cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade.html).

Or you could stop using the Hibernate Session, and use the standard JPA API instead.

Comment: Getting rid of hibernate session is not an option also throughout the code I've used the JPA annotations for mapping. So only way which appears is to remove the CASCADETYPE.ALL & explicitly update the child objects, issuing another query to the db?

Comment: No. My answer tells you how to do: use the Cascade annotation. That doesn't prevent you from using JPA mapping annotations. You just need this additional Hibernate annotation to specify a cascade option that does not exist in JPA.

Comment: The @Cascade annote is hibernate-specific, so not for JPA-only (like what the OP is asking for)

Comment: @Amalgovinus you're missing the point: there is no way to use a standard JPA cascade type to cascade an operation (SAVE_UPDATE) that is Hibernate-specific, and thus doesn't exist in JPA. So either you stop using Hibernate-specific operations like SAVE_UPDATE (and use persist/merge), and then you can use standard JPA cascade options, or you accept to use hibernate-specific operations, and thus need to also use Hibernate-specific annotations. The OP accepted the answer, so I think the answer was the one he wanted.

Answer (score 10):

`CascadeType.ALL` includes `CascadeType.REMOVE` too.
The solution is to use all `CascadeType.*` you need except `CascadeType.REMOVE`, like so:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE}))
```

in your UserGroup definitions.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost always a code smell when propagating from child to parent entity, it should be the other way round.

From [Cascading best practices](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/):

> Cascading only makes sense only for Parent – Child associations (the
> Parent entity state transition being cascaded to its Child entities).
> Cascading from Child to Parent is not very useful and usually, it’s a
> mapping code smell.

From [Hibernate best practices](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-best-practices/):

> 12. Avoid cascade remove for huge relationships
>     Most developers (myself included) get a little nervous when they see a
>     CascadeType.REMOVE definition for a relationship. It tells Hibernate
>     to also delete the related entities when it deletes this one. There is
>     always the fear that the related entity also uses cascade remove for
>     some of its relationships and that Hibernate might delete more
>     database records than intended. During all the years I’ve worked with
>     Hibernate, this has never happened to me, and I don’t think it’s a
>     real issue. But cascade remove makes it incredibly hard to understand
>     what exactly happens if you delete an entity. And that’s something you
>     should always avoid. If you have a closer look at how Hibernate
>     deletes the related entities, you will find another reason to avoid
>     it. Hibernate performs 2 SQL statements for each related entity: 1
>     SELECT statement to fetch the entity from the database and 1 DELETE
>     statement to remove it. This might be OK, if there are only 1 or 2
>     related entities but creates performance issues if there are large
>     numbers of them.